# Django - Filtering with default

Tags: python, django

I have a method `visible` on a `QuerySet` class which should return all articles an user can see. If the user is not logged in, all articles with `min_age` should'nt be visible, otherwise, if the user is logged in, all articles which `min_age` is lower than the user's age should be visible. I wrote this code but I think it can be improved. These `raise AttributeError` aren't good practice, I know, but how can I improve it?

```
    def visible(self, request=None):
        articles = self.filter(hidden=False)

        try:
            if request is not None:
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    if request.user.userprofile.has_filled_out:
                        articles = articles.filter(min_age__lte=request.user.userprofile.age)
                    else:
                        raise AttributeError
                else:
                    raise AttributeError
            else:
                raise AttributeError
        except AttributeError:
            articles = articles.filter(min_age=None)

        return articles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all those conditions into single IF using AND/OR. return limited queryset in ELSE branch.

Comment: Omg I am so dumb. I don't know why I didn't think that way! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thats how we learn, cheers ;)